# Researching relative's WW II Italian military service?

Tags: military-records, world-war-2, russia, italy

Oral family history says that an uncle (my late grandmother's son) was killed during the Italian campaign in Russia. I have no details of the military unit he was in. My efforts to obtain details of his service from the Italian bureaucracies have yielded very minimal results.

Is it possible to:

1. establish the military unit my uncle served under?
2. identify the area that it was sent to?
3. research the names of those who died in that specific campaign?

Any reference to relevant on line web sites would be good, otherwise any references to relevant Italian archives would also be good.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question wherever possible.